# How does the maxConcurrentOperationCount of the NSURLSession delegateQueue effects task concurency

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I'am using AFNetworking 3.0 which uses `NSURLSessionDataTask` and also an operationQueue (property of the `AFURLSessionManager`), which is used as the delegateQueue for the `NSURLSession`

so simply put

`AFURLSessionManager.operationQueue` == `NSURLSession.delegateQueue`

AFNetworking 3 code

```
self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
self.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:self.operationQueue];
```

from the Apple docs. to NSURLSession delegateQueue

*An operation queue for scheduling the delegate calls and completion handlers. The queue need not be a serial queue. If nil, the session creates a serial operation queue for performing all delegate method calls and completion handler calls.*

**does setting the `self.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;` means that there will be max. 4 simultaneously handled `NSURLSessionDataTask`? and setting it to = 1 (default of AFNetworking) means there is only one task at the time, and it must finish for the other one to begin?**

Or i'am i wrong and this only affects the delegate message delivery, meaning that setting it to 4 can trigger a delegate callback on 4 different threads... and setting to 1 means that the callback is always on the same thread, but the tasks are handled concurrently anyway

Comment: Is there a typo in the quote of the Apple docs above? Instead of "The queue need not be a serial queue" it should be "The queue should be a serial queue". It's so obvious that I don't dare edit it, for fear there's something I'm missing. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1411597-sessionwithconfiguration

Answer (score 6):

That queue is the delegate queue, so it should only affect delegate message delivery.

When you create an `NSURLSession` you give it a configuration object of type `NSURLSessionConfiguration`.

`NSURLSessionConfiguration`  includes a property `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` that lets you control the number of simultaneous connections to a single host.  That's the only mechanism I'm aware of that lets you control the number of connections.

Comment: great, thanks for pointing out the HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost, this should be also reflected in AFNetworking as the operationQueue property is quite misleading

Comment: I just posted a comment to your comment on that github board. It's not that the AFNetworking's operationQueue property should not be public; it's that it's poorly named and thus misleading and confusing.

Comment: btw. HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1 doesn't seems to keep up to one single connection at the time, it even looks like it is ignored, because when i hit 100 requests in a loop, the server gets 100 requests almost simultaneously, so maybe a connection can server multiple requests at the same time...